# jeditable is updating mysql but returns headers in my php

Tags: php, mysql, jeditable

i use the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.edit').editable('updateCat.php', {
       indicator : "Saving...",  
       submit   : 'OK'                  
 });  });
```

my editable point in my code is

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ echo "<tr>";
echo "<td >" . $row['id_cat'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='edit' id=".$row['id_cat'].">" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
...
```

my updateCat.php follows

```
<?php
 require_once 'base.php';
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $newvalue =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
 $result=mysql_query("UPDATE category_product SET title='$newvalue' WHERE id_cat='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
echo $newvalue;
 ?>
```

when i run my php code mysql gets updated but if i don't refresh my page and try to edit again i get this in my edit field:

```
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>Untitled Document</title>    asd
```

where i should get only the edited content which in the above case would be asd. the problem appears if i try to edit the content again without refreshing. Also if i do this, mysql updates the content with  Untitled Document which is quite frustrating. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I came to this old question when the same issue occurred to me.
There were headers in the php file with the mysql connection, removed the headers and the problem solved.